# Пытаюсь сохранить комментарий пользователя в MySQL, но он не сохраняется

Tags: php, sql

Делаю простенькие комментарии, есть выбор статьи, после чего открывается статься и отображаются комментарии из базы. Все это работает и ниже есть окно для ввода своего комментария, после чего POST запрос отправляется на эту же страницу и он доходит успешно, делаю я вот что:

```
if($_POST['email'] and $_POST['text'] and $_GET['id']){
    mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO `comments` (`email`, `article`, `text`) VALUES ('$_POST[email]', $_GET[id], '$_POST[text]')");
    echo mysqli_error($link);
}/
```

Все нормально срабатывает, без ошибок, дальше в коде идут запросы на содержание статьи и комментарии и среди них есть тот самый комментарий. НО в базе этот комментарий не появляется и при перезагрузке странице он исчезает. Что за магия?) Если выполнить запрос в MySQL:

```
INSERT INTO `comments` (`email`, `article`, `text`) VALUES ('test@mail.ru', 1, 'текст комментария')
```

То все сохраняется как надо. Если после запроса на сохранение переподключится к SQL, то уже не будет комментария.

Comment: А вы уверены, что все условия вашего if срабатывают ? вот например $_GET['id'] очень подозрительно смотриться

Comment: Уверен) Он бы в комментариях не появлялся, да и я пытался выводить результат запроса, мне просто `1` писало

Comment: Тогда можно предположить, что на соединении не стоит автокоммит и при этом руками вы commit то же не давали.

Comment: И вправду, mysqli_autocommit($link, TRUE); исправил проблему. Спасибо!

Comment: А вообще вы бы лучше перешли на привязку переменных http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php  у вас тут sql инъекции и невозможность ввести комментарии с одинарными кавычками